# Google Chrome localhost error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID without option to dismiss

Tags: wordpress, ssl, wordpress-theming, trellis

I am developing a website using Roots.io stack (Trellis + Bedrock + Sage).

I am working, locally, on several sites and they're all working fine. Until today I reboot my computer > execute `vagrant up` > attempt to access the local development URL https://mysite.dev > but suddenly get an error, in Chrome, stating "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID".

Normally, I do get a similar error, but I have the option to dismiss it. But now I do not.

Via BrowserSync, I can access the site via localhost:3000 but not using the development URL.

If you're familiar with Roots, you know that Trellis generates the SSL locally as self-signed in an automated process. So I know very little about how it works outside of their documentation.

I understand that this issue seems to be a mix-match with the SSL certificates locally, but I don't really know how to troubleshoot that. I'm thinking there is a file locally that needs to be deleted and replaced. But I don't know how to generate a replacement if that's the case.

I have spent about an hour reading any articles I could find on the topic but none seem to really explain precisely what's going on in a way I can apply.

**Update: Ultimately I'm looking for a way to add an exception for the ticket in Chrome. I was able to do it in Firefox and it's working there.**

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like more of a chrome problem than a programming problem

Comment: So I've been troubleshooting this further and I was able to get the site working in Firefox when prompted to add an exception for that certificate.

So it seems I caused the issue with a change to my code base somehow (including the local VirtualBox server) but I still have not identified a way to force Chrome to make the same exception.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Don't use .dev extensions in your local URLs as this is now a real domain name extension no longer reserved for localhost.

**Long Answer:** https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Comment: Some of the answers posted here might also be of some use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74802552/2657515

Answer (score 1):

You can either

- Import this certificate using `Chrome's Options > Manage Certificates > Import`
- Or simply ignore SSL errors launching chrome with args `--ignore-certificate-errors` like `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --ignore-certificate-errors &> /dev/null &` (not recommended).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried the second option already and it made no difference unfortunately (I'm on Linux Ubuntu and tried a similar command). As for importing "this" certificate. What is "this" referring to?

Comment: You'd import the certificate of the key used to sign the certificate used on the web server.  If it's self signed, that would just be the cert itself.

Comment: "this" is current website's self signed ssl certificate.

Comment: Thank you for the recommended solutions Dan. But neither of these are working. I'm experiencing this on Mac and Linux Ubuntu.